# Is there a way to know what Gmail filters apply to a given email?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have so many filters that I don't know which ones are making some emails skip the inbox. Is there a way to know the filters that match a given email?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The workaround I use to do this is to apply labels to filtered messages.

From **Gmail >> Settings >> Filters** you can edit the behavior of existing filters (or new ones) to include **"Apply label"**, once you check that box you can assign an existing label to the filter or create a new one.

This way you can see what filters apply to a given email both inline when messages are listed (e.g. in the inbox) or from inside the email itself.

Answer (score 3):

This solution doesn't provide an efficient way to solve your issue but it might still be helpful.

Go to the Filter page. Go to "Edit" for a specific filter and then you can see the emails that fall under that filter.